# Do we want to keep model-specific tags for LLMs?

Tags: discussion

With the recent attention (pun intended) on models such as LLaMA, ChatGPT, GPT-4 and more being released by the week, we have seen a lot of new questions on this topic on our site as well.

Let's first note that I think that for questions regarding specific LLMs, AI SE seems to be the best place to put these questions.

With the increase of such questions, I have seen quite a few questions using tags which are model-specific, such as (but maybe not limited to):

- [GPT-4](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpt-4)
- [ChatGPT](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt)
- [GPT-3](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpt-3)
- [instruct-gpt](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruct-gpt)
- [BERT](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bert) (slightly older already and not as frequently used)

However, most (if not all) of the questions that use these tags could (and some do) use one or more of the following general tags:

- [gpt](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpt)
- [large-language-models](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/large-language-models)
- [language-model](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-model)
- [natural-language-processing](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language-processing)
- [transformer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformer)
- [generative-model](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generative-model)

In particular, most questions would be perfectly fine not using the model-specific tags, but simply using the `gpt` or `large-language-model` tags.

As such, I wanted to ask for your opinion on the matter. What benefits do the model-specific tags really have? I'd argue that the model-specific tags make quite little sense for the number of questions that are actually model-specific and not simply a question about a large-language model which, by coincidence, is about ChatGPT because they are using that service. In addition, the overload of model-specific tags also leads to people not knowing which tags they have to use, leading to questions such as [this one](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39933/whats-the-difference-between-gpt3-5-and-instructgpt) which is about gpt-3.5 and instruct gpt but does not use the instruct-gpt tag.

I'll entertain you with a list of questions with tags which could be generalized and do not need model-specific tags. This list will not be exhaustive. I simply spend 10 minutes looking in the tag `gpt-3`:

- [Could it be probable to quantify or measure the IQ of a super-intelligent machine like GPT?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39873/could-it-be-probable-to-quantify-or-measure-the-iq-of-a-super-intelligent-machin)
- [Why does Bing chat refuse to pretend to be an operating system or Mathematica?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39679/why-does-bing-chat-refuse-to-pretend-to-be-an-operating-system-or-mathematica)
- [Large Language Models vs Tabular Data](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39652/large-language-models-vs-tabular-data)
- [Tool for detecting AI Generated code?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39409/tool-for-detecting-ai-generated-code)
- [When would you use prompting vs. fine tuning?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39379/when-would-you-use-prompting-vs-fine-tuning)
- [Why do LLMs like GPT-3 or Bloom use Vanilla Transformer instead of long sequence variants like Transformer-XL?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39249/why-do-llms-like-gpt-3-or-bloom-use-vanilla-transformer-instead-of-long-sequence)
- [Computation required for GPT model to choose likely word from n-options where n < total vocabulary size](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39050/computation-required-for-gpt-model-to-choose-likely-word-from-n-options-where-n)
- [What makes reproducing a model like GPT3/GPT3.5/ChatGPT difficult?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38879/what-makes-reproducing-a-model-like-gpt3-gpt3-5-chatgpt-difficult) (my own question yikes)
- [How is ChatGPT maintaining context?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38674/how-is-chatgpt-maintaining-context)
- [Does ChatGPT's limited understanding of novel inputs reveal limitations in language's ability to convey meaning?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38387/does-chatgpts-limited-understanding-of-novel-inputs-reveal-limitations-in-langu)
- [Papers on Prompt Engineering](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/37205/papers-on-prompt-engineering)
- [How do I preload a conversational AI assistant like GPT-3 with complex relational data to draw on?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/36111/how-do-i-preload-a-conversational-ai-assistant-like-gpt-3-with-complex-relationa)

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me and feels very much needed. If not now, the need will come up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, I think it's fine to have tags for specific models / programs if they are highly influential. A bit like how we have tags for `alphago` and `alphazero`, for example.

However, I'm not quite sure where to draw the line between models that are "sufficiently influential" to warrant their own tags, and models that are not.

There clearly are many questions right now that do have a model-specific tag, but actually aren't model-specific. I suppose a good start would be to simply start editing tags for such questions, and afterwards we can see how many model-specific tags actually still see much use.